# Why am I getting "Multiple entries with same key: default=datacenter1 and default=datacenter1" when using Cassandra with Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

I have the following....

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  cassandra1:
    image: ...cassandra:4.0.0
    environment:
        - CASSANDRA_DC=datacenter1
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
  cassandra2:
    image: ...cassandra:4.0.0
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_DC=datacenter1
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra1
    ports:
      - "9043:9042"
    depends_on:
      - "cassandra1"
```

And the following code to configure Cassandra

```
application:
  cassandra:
    keyspace-name: test
    username: cassandra
    password: cassandra
    local-datacenter: datacenter1
    nodes:
      - host: 192.168.56.117
        port: 9042
      - host: 192.168.56.117
        port: 9043

@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.cassandra")
public class CassandraProperties {
    private String keyspaceName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String localDatacenter;
    private List<Node> nodes;
    public static class Node {
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String host;
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private Integer port;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {


    @Autowired
    private CassandraProperties properties;

    @Override
    protected SessionBuilderConfigurer getSessionBuilderConfigurer() {
        return new SessionBuilderConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public CqlSessionBuilder configure(CqlSessionBuilder cqlSessionBuilder) {
                List<CassandraProperties.Node> nodes = properties.getNodes();
                nodes.forEach(
                        node ->
                                cqlSessionBuilder.addContactPoint(
                                        InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(
                                                node.getHost(),
                                                node.getPort()
                                        )
                                )
                );
                cqlSessionBuilder.withAuthCredentials(properties.getUsername(), properties.getPassword());
                cqlSessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter(properties.getLocalDatacenter());
                return cqlSessionBuilder;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return properties.getKeyspaceName();
    }
}
```

But when I try to run the application I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: default=datacenter1 and default=datacenter1
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.collect.ImmutableMap.conflictException(ImmutableMap.java:215)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.collect.ImmutableMap.checkNoConflict(ImmutableMap.java:209)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.checkNoConflictInKeyBucket(RegularImmutableMap.java:147)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.fromEntryArray(RegularImmutableMap.java:110)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.build(ImmutableMap.java:393)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.ProgrammaticArguments$Builder.build(ProgrammaticArguments.java:418)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildDefaultSessionAsync(SessionBuilder.java:844)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildAsync(SessionBuilder.java:817)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSystemSession(CqlSessionFactoryBean.java:539)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CqlSessionFactoryBean.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
        ... 94 common frames omitted
```

What am I missing?

To explain a little bit I am using different ports since they are different containers. They show up in peers table so I think the servers are configured right but if there is an easier way to do multiple ports without the custom builder I am good with that too.

Comment: Close with no comment about reasoning? Also I tried to debug and I am not sure if it is related but it seems to call protected SessionBuilderConfigurer getSessionBuilderConfigurer() { 2x I also tried using a single endpoint and that failed the same way